# getting cell value from a table

Tags: php, javascript, html

i am having a problem, i have a script that prints a table while getting values from the database, now, my problem is i want the values of each cell clickable, i know how to make that, i added

```
<a href="sample.php">row from query result is printed here</a>
```

everytime it prints a value in the cell

now, each cell has different values, and when ever a clicker clicks one of the values i have no idea on how will i get the value of the cell that the user clicked, any suggestions??

Comment: If you're open to jQuery, I can provide you with the solution

Comment: Do you want to be sending the values to your server side or do you need them on the client?

Comment: @KonstantinDinev either way will be great

Comment: @asprin sure thing sir, i am open to any solution

Comment: Have a look at Mangala's answer. It doesn't even require JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<a href="sample.php?value=<?php echo $yourvalue?>">row from query result is printed here</a>
```

You can pass value as a GET variable.

(edited below)

**OR**

using jquery [[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fkPpw/)]

```
$(".tdclass").click(function(){
   alert($(this).text());
   //OR 
   //alert($(this).html());
});​
```

You can easily identify `td` using class. Oterwise you can use `$(td).click()`.

Answer (score 0):

add a class (say 'click_td') to each cell of the table. and then do this is JS.

```
     $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#table_1 .click_td').click(function(){
     alert($(this).text());
  });

 });​
```

Comment: you'd want to use `.on()` and attach to the table

Comment: it would be .text() instead of .val()

Comment: Can anyone confirm whether POST works with anchor tags? If it does, it certainly would be a big thing that I get to learn today.

Comment: I thought so. I always be on the safe side and let someone else clear the doubt rather than stamp my authority on anything xD That's why I didn't jump to a conclusion that post with anchor tag is not possible

Answer (score 0):

I asume you want to treat the data with javascript. So, create a function in javascript:

```
function handle_db_data(var data){...do whatever you want here...}
```

And in order to call that function with the database data, you can do this:

```
<a name="row1" onclick="handle_db_data(ROW_FROM_DATABASE);">ROW_FROM_DATABASE</a>
```

Using jQuery would be even more easy!

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="sample.php?id=<?php echo $row['value']; ?>"><?php echo $row['value']; ?></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not vague but has little information, for instance, where do you want to keep the identifier of each cell? will it be in a hidden input field or will it be in a the link or even a javascript function? Either way this would be how you want to do this:

```
echo '<table>';
$counter = 1;

/* Assuming the database output is an associative array. */
foreach($db_data as $item) {
   echo '<tr>';
   echo '<td>'.$counter.'</td>';
   /* if the row identifier will be in your link. */
   echo '<td><a href="sample.php?rowid='.$item['pk_row_id'].'">row from query result is printed here</a></td>';
   /* if the row identifier will be a hidden input field. */
   echo '<td><input type="hidden" value="'.$item['pk_row_id'].'" name="rowid" id="rowid" />';
   /* if the row identifier will be in a javascript function on click. */
   echo '<td><a href="void(0)" onclick="userclickaction('.$item['pk_row_id'].')>Click Me to edit</a></td>`enter code here`';
   echo '</tr>';

   /* Increment counter. */
   $counter++; 
}

echo '</table>';
```